How to Record UIView with Several AVPlayerLayer?
I'm trying to record UIView which has several playing AVPlayerLayer...!
Howevver it doesn't work when I record that UIView.
It shows just Red Screen(Because I set red color to that view)
-> Videos are not shown...!
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var screenRecorder: ScreenRecorder?
    var playerView: PlayerView?
    var player: AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // PlayerView 설정
        playerView = PlayerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        if let playerView = playerView {
            self.view.addSubview(playerView)
            setupPlayer(in: playerView)
        }

        // ScreenRecorder 초기화
        if let playerView = playerView {
            screenRecorder = ScreenRecorder(view: playerView)
        }

        // 녹화 버튼 추가
        let startButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 400, width: 100, height: 50))
        startButton.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        startButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        startButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startRecording), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(startButton)

        let stopButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 400, width: 100, height: 50))
        stopButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        stopButton.backgroundColor = .red
        stopButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stopRecording), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(stopButton)
    }

    private func setupPlayer(in view: PlayerView) {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mp4") else { return }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        playerView?.playerLayer?.player = player
        player?.play()
    }

    @objc func startRecording() {
        screenRecorder?.startRecording()
    }

    @objc func stopRecording() {
        player?.pause() // 비디오 재생을 멈춤
        screenRecorder?.stopRecording { [weak self] outputURL in
            guard let url = outputURL else { return }
            print("Video saved to: \(url)")
            self?.navigateToSharingViewController(with: url)
        }
    }

    private func navigateToSharingViewController(with url: URL) {
        let sharingViewController = SharingViewController()
        sharingViewController.videoURL = url
        navigationController?.pushViewController(sharingViewController, animated: true)
    }
}



-> This is my VC to show one AVplayerlayer...! But it also doesn't work
